# Create own css template or buy ready made css template in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm confused with some css templates in bootstrap.

I've been a developer for years already but I never worked in a company that let me create an entire website as front-end developer say for example an e-commerce site.

So if someone would say "do an e-commerce site", do I have to ask them for a ready made css template? If so, then is it possible there are already other sites that bought it, other than me, e.g. we may have the same web face?

I am not really an expert in css nor an artist. I have created a website for personal use but it was pure bootstrap. I can see other templates in bootstrap; they have other components manipulated, like a different menu which is not present in their list of components.

How did they do that? Is it another individual css, js, html component? Do I have to create my own component sometimes?

For you to understand me, I can create relatively easily any site written in either React or Angular but I cannot create my own css design.

Answer (score 0):

The examples and templates that you see in Bootstrap uses the Bootstrap framework, but the CSS and JS design components are changed to better define what the user wants it to be like.

For example

```
form-group-lg select.form-control{height:46px;line-height:46px}
```

This is the pre-defined CSS value from Bootstrap CDN, changing this CSS value to something else, changes your design, but you still are based on Boostrap. Basically, Bootstrap is not only about design, it's following a library, a framework, a skeleton to make your web development (specially frontend) easier.